# Docker container not able to read http link - camel

Tags: docker, spring-boot, apache-camel

So I am working on creating a **docker container** for one of my `Camel` `Spring boot` project in **Windows**. In the project, at the beginning of my `camelcontext.xml` I have the following piece of code -

```
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd 
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    .
    .
    // remaining part of code
```

Now, for the part `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd ..."` the docker container isn't able to access the .xsd files.

Also, not sure if relevant, I have another separate container that has a jhipster application and I am able to open that application in my local browser. I have also made the **DNS** changes that I found in few links online. *(by changes I mean adding 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in the virtual switch created)*

Not sure why am I not able to access the files from container and where exactly the problem is.

Below is the error that I get -

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 10 in XML document from class path resource
>   [META-INF/spring/camelContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 44;
>   cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
>
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 44;
>   cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

And at `line 10, column 44` is the code that I've pasted above.

PS - the xml file is validated, I check it [here](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the problem is not related to DNS by replacing `www.springframework.org` with the ip address that you can obtain by pinging `www.springframework.org`
2. Start the container with `--network=host` in docker run command.

Comment: the changes you meant in the `camelcontext.xml`?
and for `--network=host` what shall I put as host? my local IP?

Comment: yes. Just test that to make sure that the problem is not related to DNS.

Comment: Hi @yamenk, I tried your suggestions - changed url with ip address and added `--network=host` as well. Also mapped my directory usng `-v` but didn't get any solution.
I have added the error that I am getting in the question.